# This is a problem from LightOJ (Large Division 1214) , I do not why my code is not accepted

Tags: c++, biginteger

I am a beginner level student, please help me to understand what is the problem in this code.

Problem statement:

> Given two integers, `a` and `b`, you should check whether `a` is divisible by `b` or not. We know that an integer `a` is divisible by an integer `b` if and only if there exists an integer `c` such that `a = b * c`.
>
> **Input**
> Input starts with an integer `T` (≤ 525), denoting the number of test cases.
>
> Each case starts with a line containing two integers `a` (`-10200 ≤ a ≤ 10200`) and `b` (`|b| > 0`, `b` fits into a 32 bit signed integer). Numbers will not contain leading zeroes.
>
> **Output**
> For each case, print the case number first. Then print 'divisible' if `a` is divisible by `b`. Otherwise print 'not divisible'.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 6
> 101 101
> 0 67
> -101 101
> 7678123668327637674887634 101
> 11010000000000000000 256
> -202202202202000202202202 -101
> ```
>
> **Output for Sample Input**
>
> ```
> Case 1: divisible
> Case 2: divisible
> Case 3: divisible
> Case 4: not divisible
> Case 5: divisible
> Case 6: divisible
> ```

My code:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()            
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);

    for(int t=1;t<=T;t++){
        string a;
        cin >> a;
        long long int b;
        scanf("%lld",&b);
        b = abs(b);
        long long int mod = 0;
        long long int sz = a.size();
        int i=0;
        if(a[0] == '-') i=1;
        
        for( ;i<sz;i++){
            mod = mod*10+a[i]-'0';
            mod = mod%b;
        }
            
        if(mod == 0)  printf("Case %d : divisible\n",t);
        else        printf("Case %d : not divisible\n",t);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem statement says that `-10200 ≤ a ≤ 10200` but some of the values of `a` are larger than that? Why are you mixing scanf and cin? What is the problem with your code? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Bad idea to mix `cin` and `scanf` in the same program.  Don't do it.  Just use `cin`.

Comment: I notice your code puts a space between the case number and the `:` whereas the sample output does not.

Comment: I have now used cin in both of the input , but still giving me the verdict wrong answer

Comment: Well, what happens when you put the sample input in?  Does it give the right answers?

Comment: Yes, the sample input gives right answer

Comment: Thank you very much, there was the space issue between case and the answer, I am a beginner level student and I did not know this could cause a problem, thanks a lot again, it was driving me crazy

Comment: Why on earth would it not cause a problem?  The output format was explicitly specified and you output something different.

Comment: I am sorry for that.

Comment: It's not a problem.  This is how you learn.  I did point that out at the start though, so it would have been good if you tried it. :)